# Android O failing to inflate webview after AFW enrollment

Tags: android, webview, webkit, android-webview, android-for-work

I'm using the latest Android O beta version in a Pixel XL device. 
This is my webview in xml.

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/launch_anim"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

This is how its used in my Activity class

```
WebView launch_anim = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.launch_anim);
launch_anim.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/launch_anim_centered.html");
```

This is my launch_anim_centered.html file in assets dir

```
<HTML>
<head>
    <style>
body {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<CENTER>
    <IMG SRC="launch_anim_1x.gif">
</CENTER>
</body>
</HTML>
```

The launch_anim_1x.gif file is a gif file containing an image which is rotating.
When I start the application, there is no problem in running of this activity. Then I do Android-For-Work enrollment. Post enrollment, as soon as app is launched, this activity fails to render and it throws an exception like this

```
07-28 15:39:55.352 16538-16538/? I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.google.android.webview version 58.0.3029.125 (code 303012500)
07-28 15:39:55.353 16538-16538/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-28 15:39:55.354 16538-16538/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.sample.app, PID: 16538
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sample.app/com.sample.app.ui.StartupActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                                                    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
                                                    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:720)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:418)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2654)
                                                       at com.sample.app.ui.StartupActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source:37)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                       at android.content.res.AssetManager.addAssetPathNative(Native Method)
                                                       at android.content.res.AssetManager.addAssetPathInternal(AssetManager.java:689)
                                                       at android.content.res.AssetManager.addAssetPathAsSharedLibrary(AssetManager.java:684)
                                                       at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProviderClass(WebViewFactory.java:407)
                                                       at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider(WebViewFactory.java:211)
                                                       at android.webkit.WebView.getFactory(WebView.java:2467)
                                                       at android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated(WebView.java:2462)
                                                       at android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(WebView.java:2527)
                                                       at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4536)
                                                       at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4668)
                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:597)
                                                       at android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(AbsoluteLayout.java:55)
07-28 15:39:55.354 16538-16538/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:636)
                                                       at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:581)
                                                       at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:564)
                                                       at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:551)
                                                        ... 27 more
```

This issue is only seen in Pixel and PixelXL devices. Nexus device works fine. Any help in resolving this issue is appreciated. Thanks
EDIT: New info. So I disabled the webview to see what happens but then the app crashes when trying to access CookieManager.getInstance(). This is the stacktrace:

```
07-31 09:21:51.767 11267-11557/com.airwatch.vmworkspace I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.google.android.webview version 58.0.3029.125 (code 303012500)
07-31 09:21:51.775 13243-13276/? I/ConfigUpdater: Update started

                                                  --------- beginning of crash
07-31 09:21:51.775 11267-11557/com.airwatch.vmworkspace E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
                                                                          Process: com.airwatch.vmworkspace, PID: 11267
                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                                              at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:353)
                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
                                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                              at android.content.res.AssetManager.addAssetPathNative(Native Method)
                                                                              at android.content.res.AssetManager.addAssetPathInternal(AssetManager.java:689)
                                                                              at android.content.res.AssetManager.addAssetPathAsSharedLibrary(AssetManager.java:684)
                                                                              at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProviderClass(WebViewFactory.java:407)
                                                                              at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider(WebViewFactory.java:211)
                                                                              at android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance(CookieManager.java:39)
                                                                              at com.sample.app.network.communication.MyCookieManager.<init>(MyCookieManager.java:48)
```

I think the real problem is NullPointerException on android.content.res.AssetManager.addAssetPathNative(Native Method). Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried enabling Chrome on the work profile using [DevicePolicyManager.enableSystemApp](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html) or installing it from the Play Store?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in Android O: if Chrome is disabled in one of the profiles then WebView is broken for both profiles until it's updated by Play.

To fix this issue during provisioning and avoid having to update WebView, you can enable Chrome in the work profile using [`DevicePolicyManager.enableSystemApp()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#enableSystemApp(android.content.ComponentName,%20java.lang.String)) with the package name `com.android.chrome`, and then prevent the user from disabling it using [`DevicePolicyManager.setUninstallBlocked()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#setUninstallBlocked(android.content.ComponentName,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean)).

If you then want to prevent the user from using the Chrome browser, you should use [`DevicePolicyManager.setPackagesSuspended()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#setPackagesSuspended(android.content.ComponentName,%20java.lang.String[],%20boolean)) instead of [`DevicePolicyManager.setApplicationHidden()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#setApplicationHidden(android.content.ComponentName,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean)).

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround which may help someone else. 
Before we start AFW enrollment , the developer options in device shows Webview Implementation to be Chrome. Android System Webview is disabled. At this point if I go to playstore, I can see Android System Webview but nothing happens when I click 'Enable'. After we do the AFW, and we see the managed profile has been successfully created, if I go to playstore now, I see an 'update' button for Android System Webview and I'm able to do the update. Once complete, if I look at the developer options, the webview implementation has switched from chrome to system webview. After this, if I launch my app in the work container, I do not see the crash and the app works as expected. Also, once we've removed the work profile, the webview implementation switches back to chrome.
Note that same thing happens in Nexus device also but we didn't need to do any update of webview. The webview implementation switches back and forth between chrome and system webview, and things work. Its only in Pixel that we do the update to make it work.

Comment: This workaround works, but it's a poor experience. Instead you can enable Chrome in the work profile during provisioning, and avoid having to update WebView. See my response.

Comment: This error now coming in OnePlus 5 Open Beta 1 and this workaround not working neither the one by Fred